# Как задать шаблон пользовательского ввода в консоль Java?

Tags: консоль, java

Надо вводить по два числа в строку через пробел и только так. То есть, после ввода одного числа запретить переходить на другую строку, а после ввода двух чисел автоматически переводить курсор на следующую строку. Как это сделать?

Comment: А такое вообще возможно?

Comment: Ну, если невозможно, то так и скажите. Если вы в этом уверены, конечно :)

Answer (score 1):

Запретить переходить на другую строку и вводить только цифры, к сожалению, не получится. А реализовать автоматический переход, пожалуйста. В помощь Вам функция System.in.read(). Она возвращает следующий символ, введенный в консоли. К сожалению, склейку чисел, контроль правильности и т.д. придется реализовывать самостоятельно. Когда обнаружите конец второго числа - просто посылаете в консоль "/n".